# how-to-avoid-overlapping-depth interval-ranges-when-using-a-grouping-clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to generate summary table based on grouping along the depth interval for same code. I tried a simple group by clause with Minimum From_Depth and Meximum To_Depth, but it eliminates overlapping changes. Below is the example:

```
Create Table #Lithology (
      Hole_ID varchar(10)
    , mFrom int
    , mTo int
    , Strat varchar(10)
    ,Strand varchar(10)
)

insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 0, 2, 'CzD3', 'ALU');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 2, 4, 'CzD3', 'ALU');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 4, 6, 'CzD3', 'SCR');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 6, 8, 'CzD3', 'SCR');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 6, 8, 'CzD3', 'SCR');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 8, 10, 'CzD2', 'CIDW');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 10, 12, 'CzD2', 'CIDW');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 12, 14, 'CzD2', 'CIDO');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 14, 16, 'CzD2', 'CIDW');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 16, 18, 'CzD2', 'CIDW');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 18, 20, 'NAM', 'TNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 20, 22, 'NAM', 'TNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 22, 24, 'NAM', 'SNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 24, 26, 'NAM', 'SNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 26, 28, 'NAM', 'SONAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 28, 30, 'NAM', 'SONAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 30, 32, 'NAM', 'SNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 32, 34, 'NAM', 'SNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 34, 36, 'NAM', 'NNAM');
insert into #Lithology (Hole_ID, mFrom, mTo, Strat, Strand ) values ('MD4803', 36, 38, 'NAM', 'NNAM');


select Hole_ID
, min(mFrom) StartDepth
, max( mTo) EndDepth
, Strat, Strand
from #Lithology
group by Hole_ID, Strat, Strand
order by MIN(mFrom)
```

it returns the following results with overlapping depth ranges.

```
Hole_ID StartDepth  EndDepth    Strat   Strand
MD4803  0           4           CzD3    ALU
MD4803  4           8           CzD3    SCR
MD4803  8           18          CzD2    CIDW
MD4803  12          14          CzD2    CIDO
MD4803  18          22              NAM TNAM
MD4803  22          34          NAM SNAM
MD4803  26          30          NAM SONAM
MD4803  34          38          NAM NNAM
```

The expected result is as below with no overlapping interval:

```
Hole_ID StartDepth  EndDepth    Strat   Strand
MD4803  0           4           CzD3    ALU
MD4803  4           8           CzD3    SCR
MD4803  8           12          CzD2    CIDW
MD4803  12          14          CzD2    CIDO
MD4803  14          18          CzD2    CIDW
MD4803  18          22          NAM TNAM
MD4803  22          26          NAM SNAM
MD4803  26          30          NAM SONAM
MD4803  30          34          NAM SNAM
MD4803  34          38          NAM NNAM
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please-edit-your-question-title-and-remove-the-hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a recusive CTE to identify groups:

```
;WITH lithCTE
AS
(
    -- number the rows for each hole id (in case any data in the sequence is missing)
    SELECT * ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Hole_Id ORDER BY mFrom
                        ) AS rn
    FROM #Lithology
)
,retCTE
AS
(
    --starting from the top of each hole in the dataset, identify groups
    SELECT Hole_Id, mFrom, mTo, Strat,Strand, rn, 1 AS grp
    FROM lithCTE
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT l.Hole_Id, l.mFrom, l.mTo, l.Strat,l.Strand, l.rn, 
    CASE    WHEN r.Hole_Id = l.Hole_id  
            AND r.strat = l.strat 
            AND r.Strand = l.Strand  
            THEN r.grp ELSE r.grp + 1 END AS grp
    FROM retCTE AS r
    JOIN lithCTE AS l
    ON l.hole_id = r.hole_id AND l.rn = r.rn + 1
)
SELECT Hole_ID
, MIN(mFrom) StartDepth
, MAX( mTo) EndDepth
, Strat, Strand
FROM retCTE
GROUP BY Hole_ID, Strat, Strand,grp
ORDER BY Hole_ID,StartDepth
```

There's probably a simpler solution but for the moment it eludes me.

Comment: Hi Ed,
Thanks for the prompt response. It works for a single hole.
I forgot to mentioned that we have around 7000 holes and each hole would have 50 meter average hole depth(i.e. 25 layers in a hole) of holes in actual table. The grouping would be within each hole.   
I’ve managed to resolve the issue as below. But I prefer your solution.  My solution works for  small data volume. But it is very slow for the whole table. Based on your solution I will try adding Hole_ID loop.

Comment: Forgot to provide my code in my previous response. Here it is.Stplited into 3. Step 1 is 
Alter View Test_CTE_Litho_mFrom
As
with temp as (
select *, row_number() over (order by Hole_ID, mFrom, strand) as rownum
from tblDHLithology 
where Hole_ID like 'MD6%'
)
select Temp.Hole_id, Temp.mFrom, prev.Strand PreviousStrand, temp.Strand, Temp.rownum from temp 
LEFT JOIN Temp prev ON prev.rownum = Temp.rownum - 1
LEFT JOIN Temp nex ON nex.rownum = Temp.rownum + 1
where temp.Strand <> prev.Strand or prev.Strand is null

Comment: -- Step 2 Create View to retrieve Highest mTo Group By Hole_ID, Strand and mTo
Alter View Test_CTE_Litho_mTo
As
with temp1 as (
select *, row_number() over (order by Hole_ID, mFrom, strand) as rownum
from tblDHLithology 
where Hole_ID like 'MD6%'
)
select temp1.Hole_id, temp1.mTo, temp1.Strand, nex.Strand NextStrand, Temp1.rownum from temp1 
LEFT JOIN temp1 prev ON prev.rownum = temp1.rownum - 1
LEFT JOIN temp1 nex ON nex.rownum = temp1.rownum + 1
where temp1.Strand <> nex.Strand or nex.Strand is null

Comment: -- Step 3 Creeate select statement to create PIVOT table of mFrom, mTo based on two above views
-- V_ROWNUM is required to match the INNER JOIN
select a.Hole_id, a.mFrom, b.mTo, a.Strand
from (
select *, row_number() over (order by Hole_ID, mFrom, strand) as v_rownum
from Test_CTE_Litho_mFrom
-- order by hole_id, mFrom
) as a
inner join (
select *, row_number() over (order by Hole_ID, mTo, strand) as v_rownum
from Test_CTE_Litho_mTo
-- order by hole_id, mTo
) as b on a.v_rownum = b.v_rownum
where a.hole_id = 'MD6002'

Comment: @MawMawOo - my solution should work for multiple holes

Comment: Hi Ed - Yes, you're right. Your solution works for multiple holes. Thanks for that. Though slow for the whole table, it is a better solution.Thanks again. Maw Maw